# set/reset GPIO though command line is not working as expected

Tags: linux, command-line, gpio, sysfs

I am trying to set/reset the GPIO value through sysfs. I took [this](http://raspberrypi-aa.github.io/session2/bash.html) document as reference.

At one point I am little confused, the scenario is given below

exported gpio 200 to test

```
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# echo "out" > direction   <-- set the direction as write(out)
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat direction            < -- just to verify
out
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# echo 1 > value           < -- set value as 1(high)
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat value                
1
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# echo 0 > value           < -- set value Low again
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat value
0
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat direction
out
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# echo "in" > direction      < -- change the direction to read the pin
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat direction
in
mx6q:/sys/class/gpio/gpio200# cat value                 < -- what i am expecting here is 0 (last set value)  
1
```

So regardless the value i Set before , i am always reading a high value. is this really expected behavior? 
I am confused at two points,

1. why  the previously set value is not persisting after i change the direction?
2. what does the "Direction" really means, if i can cat for the value in both "in" and "out" case?

Please suggest a proper document to read to get a clear idea about GPIO operations. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Please suggest a proper document to read"* -- The datasheet or TRM for the SoC that you are using.  Typically the pin controller (e.g. Atmel's) always allows a read of the logic state of that pin, regardless if the pin is used for input or output, GPIO or multiplexed to a peripheral, digital or analog (e.g. ADC input) function.

Comment: Okay, mine is an iMX SoC, i will find and read the corresponding document. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does the "Direction" really means, if i can cat for the value in both "in" and "out" case?

This question is a little unclear, but maybe this helps:

If `direction` is `out`, then the data in `value` defines the logic level you want to *set* on the GPIO pin.

If the `direction` is `in`, then the data in `value` is the logical level currently being *read* from the GPIO pin.

> why the previously set value is not persisting after i change the direction?

Imagine that you have the pin tied to ground.

If you set direction to `out` and write `1` to `value`, then of course when you read back `value` you will see `1` because that's what you just requested.

If you were then set to set `direction` to `in`, `value` would now read `0` because you have the pin tied to ground, so you are currently reading a logical 0 from the pin.

Comment: So you are saying like scenario above is a special case of grounded GPIO pin. and in general I could read back the  same value i set after changing the direction? please correct if i am wrong. Thank you for the support :)

Comment: I'm not saying that, no.  I'm saying that it is perfectly usual for the content of `value` to change when you switch `direction` because the meaning of the file is different in each case.  When `direction` is `out` the meaning of `value` is "I am requesting this value".  When `direction` is `in`, the meaning of `value` is "This is the value currently read from the pin".  They are different things and you would not expect the value to stay the same.